# use Angular local storage to store form data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to use Angular local storage to store form data.  When a form is filled in I need to store the data to local storage and then see it in a

tag. Here is my code:

```js
  <form data-ng-submit="makeNote()" class="todo-form">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="noteText" placeholder="Enter new ToDo item" />
                        <br />
                       <input type="submit" value="Add Note" />
                    </form>
<p>{{noteData}}</p>
```

```js
var noteStorageKey = 'area' + areaId + 'climb' + climbId + 'noteStore';
// Local Storage for Notes
$scope.makeNote = function() {
  var noteToSave = $scope.noteText;
  $localStorage[noteStorageKey] = noteToSave;
  $scope.noteData = noteToSave;
}

 $scope.noteMyData = function() {
 $scope.noteData = $localStorage[noteStorageKey];

 }

$scope.removeNote = function() {
     delete $localStorage[noteStorageKey];
     $scope.noteData = '';
}
```

Note: the long storage key is used to store in a specific key per page.

Comment: What is the question? You already use it.

Comment: Hi estus, thanks for responding. Its not storing to local storage.  Im not getting any errors but when I debug I can see it is not storing

Comment: Its not taking the data from the form when I type it in.  That's my question.  Why is it not taking my form data and storing it?

Comment: It isn't just local storage. It is `$localstorage`. Is it ngStorage service? In this case you can't save anything with `$localStorage[noteStorageKey] = ...`. It should be `$localStorage.set(...)`. I would suggest to read the manual.